# Input text field not responding normally only in chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

My website which I'm currently building (password protected website) is not showing a cursor in the text fields when clicking into the fields, only seems to be happening in Chrome.  I can still type in the text field! It seems I have to click outside of the browser window to resume normal behaviour.

I decided to create a test file which can be accessed here:
https:// www . theglowhouse .com/test.php I don't want to actively link to the site here, so please remove the spaces.

username: guest

pass: showtestsite

The code on this page is:

```
<input type="text" value="some text" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='some text'}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'some text') {this.value=''}">
```

I can only reproduce this problem when following the exact sequence:
1) Start a new session
2) Visit any website first
3) Visit the test page as stated above
4) Click into the text field, text field isn't active.
5) Click outside the browser or similar action and then click back into the text field and everything seems fine again.

If you are trying this for the first time, then you most likely won't need to start a new session and you should be able to see the problem straight away.

A few notes:
If I try to load the site again, then I cannot reproduce the bug unless I start a new session.

If I open up chrome and stop the first page/homepage loading and run the test page immediately, I can't reproduce the bug either. I thought that was particularly odd.

I've tried this on a few different machines with the same problem, I can also see the same problem on google canary, but couldn't reproduce it on chromium.

Finally if I disable the username / password on the website, I can't reproduce the bug at all no matter what I do, which is a solution long term, however during the testing phase it would be nice to test the site and have it working whilst keeping it password protected.

Comment: I just tried everything you said and did not have any problem. I would suggest you deactivate all browser plugins, delete your cache and temps files and try again. If it still fails, reinstall chrome. In any case, I would suggest using placeholder="some text" instead of onblure and on focus

Comment: Hello Patrick, thanks for your comment.  I have already done exactly as you said. I have had others already reproduce the error and I can also reproduce it on my cell phone using chrome on android, which I wasn't expecting! If you visit the main site instead of the test page and naviagte to the checkout, you can see my Dev has used some other code which includes a placeholder. Thank you anyway. Can I ask, are you using 32/64 bit chrome?